# Need to call same class twice in testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

    <suite name="example suite 1" verbose="1" parallel="false" >
    <test name="Regression suite 1" preserve-order="true" >
      <classes>
        <class name="AppLaunch"/>
        <class name="Login">  
          <methods>
             <include name="Method1"/>
             <include name="Method2"/>    
          </methods>
         </class>
       <class name="SearchAccount"/>
       <class name="LogOut"/>
       <class name="Login">
         <methods>
            <include name="Method3"/>     
         </methods>
       </class>
     </classes>
   </test>
 </suite>
```

When the above test is configured using testing.xml, it throwsjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependency: Login.Method3

Is there any way to call the same class twice only from testing.xml?

Comment: Please edit your question and kindly add a trimmed down version of what your test classes look like.

Comment: Why do want to call Method3 in different class tag ? Instead you can call method3 in same class.

Answer (score 0):

**classes** are collection of **class**.
**Class** will have **methods** (whether you wanna include or exclude that's up to you.)

In your case, it doesn't seems to be convincing that you are defining class two times.

Instead call method3 in same methods tag under `<class name="Login">`

```
<class name="Login">
   <methods>
       <include name="Method1"/>
       <include name="Method2"/>
       <include name="Method3"/>    
   </methods>
</class>
```

Is there any way to call the same class twice only from testing.xml? -- **In 
 this scenario, There is no need of it.**

**Update**

If your scenario is like, you want to run testMethod3 after executing some test methods of logout class, then you have to go with dependencies provided by TestNG.

```
public class Logout {
    @Test(groups={"logout-test-case"})
    public void testLogout1(){
        System.out.println("---Test Log----");
    }
}
```

Now your login class testMethod3 should look like this :

```
public class login{

        @Test
        public void testMethod1(){
        //some steps to perform test method1
        }

         @Test
        public void testMethod2(){
        //some steps to perform test method2
        }

        @Test(dependsOnGroups={"logout-test-case"})
        public void testLogout3(){
            System.out.println("---Test method 3----");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want the "Method3" of Login class to get executed after the Logout class.

Comment: Then you should use : @Test(groups={"logoutTestCase"}) on particular method of logout class. And your testmethod3 should use : @Test(dependsOnGroups={"logoutTestCase"}) #see my updated answer.